# Gitignore files and folders isn't working as wished

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and I want to choose which files I want to push. Some files are private for private purposes obviously so I dont want git to track them. I created a .gitignore file and I added which folder and files I dont want to be tracked. So in this case I dont want the Classes folder to be tracked and I dont want the settings.json file to be tracked either. So I saved the `.gitignore` file and did

```
git add .
git commit -m "test"
git push origin master
```

but every single file still got pushed into my rep on github

Also as you could see the Class folder is still connected to my git rep because everytime I do a change for instance the file in the folder turns orange as you could see on `main.cpp`

[image: Here is how it looks like]

Comment: Could you also provide the contents of your `.gitignore` file? Most likely the configuration of the file is not correct.

Comment: The contents of my .gitignore file is in the image that I posted. But here it is:

C++/.vscode/settings.json

C++/Classes

Comment: No images of code/text allowed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

If your `.gitignore` is already in the `C++` folder, then its rules should not start with `C++/...`

Once you edit your `.gitignore` to remove the leading `C++/`, make sure your files were not already added to the index and/or committed: that would not be ignored anyway.

Check your .gitignore is working with [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v -- a/file/which/should/be/ignored
```